# Convert query from MySQL to PostgreSQL: unlucky employees

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to get this query for a database question( Unlucky wmployees) to Postgres. I am having a hard time getting it right

```
CREATE PROCEDURE unluckyEmployees()
BEGIN
    SET @rn =0;
    SELECT dep_name, emp_number, total_salary FROM
    (SELECT dep_name, emp_number, total_salary, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum  FROM
    (SELECT name AS dep_name, IF(e.id IS NULL, 0, COUNT(*)) AS emp_number,  IFNULL(SUM(salary), 0) AS total_salary
     FROM Department d LEFT JOIN Employee e ON e.Department = d.id
    GROUP BY d.id HAVING COUNT(*) < 6 ORDER BY SUM(salary) DESC, COUNT(*) DESC, d.id) t )tt  WHERE mod(seqnum, 2) = 1;
END
```

I am hoping to get the query in postgres. Tried setting @rn to row_number() but still not working.

Comment: PostgreSQL and MySQL are not compatible. Start again from the basics. Make each part of the query work and build it up, without trying to copy code from MySQL. And why such an old version of PostgreSQL? At least upgrade to 9.6, though preferably 15, as 9.1 hasn't had security patches in ages. https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Comment: The hack with the variables is usually used to workaround the fact that old MySQL didn't support modern SQL like `row_number()`. But without knowing what this hack exactly does in this case, this can't really be answered (and the missing formatting of the query doesn't make it easier to understand). So please **[edit]** your question and explain what the underlying problem is, that this query solves.